# selenium in python. trying to select element

Tags: python, selenium

UPDATE:  I found out what caused the issue in my original post, but don't know how to solve.  Here is some more of my code.  I first did a search, after which my page in firefox jumped to www.flickr.com/searc/?text=volleybal.
but apparently my browser object still sits on www.flickr.com.  How can I update it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.flickr.com')
s = browser.find_element_by_id('search-field')
s.send_keys('volleyball')
s.submit()
s = browser.find_element_by_class_name("style-button")
#s = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-style-value = 'minimalism']")
s.click()
```

---

original post:

I'm experimenting with selenium, and I want to select the following element:

`<li class="style-button minimalist" data-style-value="minimalism" data-tooltip-title="Minimalist" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Minimalist">`

I have tried the following, but none of them work:

`s = browser.find_element_by_class_name("style-button minimalist")`

`s = browser.find_element_by_class_name("style-button.minimalist")`

`s = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.style-button.minimalist")`

`s = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".style-button.minimalist")`

How can I select this element?

Comment: I think it's probably because you're looking at 2 class names there. Select only by "style-button". "style-button minimalist" is not a single class. I'm not a Selenium expert though so could be wrong. If you only want one element though, set an `id` and use `find_element_by_id` - I find that's clearer usually

Comment: None of them works? Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try an XPath here:

```
s = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'style-button')]")
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: No, that didn't work.  I also tried: ```s = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-style-value = 'minimalism']")``` but always the same error: "unable to locate element".

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Added `browser.refresh()`after `s.submit()`

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use *absolute xpath*. It for that button will be:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]
```

Moreover, I found that sometimes the page is not loaded and the selenium searches for the element, which results in error. You can wait for the element to appear. You can find more information [here](http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/).

With the combination of these, your code will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.flickr.com/')
s = browser.find_element_by_id('search-field')
s.send_keys('volleyball')
s.submit()

s = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]")))
s.click()
```

Comment: Why is an absolute XPath the solution here? These can be very brittle and should not be used unless completely necessary.